# three different table in one views laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I would like to display three different table in one views using laravel 5.2. but it seems i am having problem on it.

my HomeController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $about = DB::select('select * from about');
        $teams = DB::select('select * from teams');
        $services = DB::select('select * from services');

        return view('master', ['about' => $about], ['teams' => $teams], ['services' => $services]);
    }
}
```

in my views:

```
@foreach ($about as $abt)
      <h4>{{$abt->title}}</h4>
      <span class="semi-separator center-block"></span>
      <p>{{$abt->description}}</p>
@endforeach

@foreach ($teams as $team)
     <div class="creative-symbol cs-creative">
        <img src="assets/images/new/{{$team->icon}}" alt="">
        <span class="semi-separator center-block"></span>
        <h4><b>{{$team->title}}</b></h4>
        <p>{{$team->description}}</p>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

i cant display the third one which is the $services. pls help me.
when i add the third one it will display an error

Comment: What do you mean you can't display the third one? You've only posted code for two.

Comment: when i add the third one it will display an error @ceejayoz

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this:

```
        return view('master', ['about' => $about], ['teams' => $teams], ['services' => $services]);
```

to this:

```
        return view('master', ['about' => $about, 'teams' => $teams, 'services' => $services]);
```

Comment: No problem! I love laravel! Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 5.1, I found the following code in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`:

```
if (! function_exists('view')) {
    /**
     * Get the evaluated view contents for the given view.
     *
     * @param  string  $view
     * @param  array   $data
     * @param  array   $mergeData
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory
     */
    function view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
    {
        $factory = app(ViewFactory::class);

        if (func_num_args() === 0) {
            return $factory;
        }

        return $factory->make($view, $data, $mergeData);
    }
}
```

This is the function you are attempting to call.  Notice how many arguments there are (there are 3). You are attempting pass in 4.  I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
return view('master', [
    'about' => $about, 
    'teams' => $teams, 
    'services' => $services
]);
```

This is now calling the same function, but only passing *two* arguments.